# How to Clip content with rounded corners in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, rounded-corners, clipping

I've attempted to have a `<Grid/>` (with interactive stuff inside, not just an image) **clipped** with rounded corners (a `<Border/>` or a `<Rectangle/>`, whatever works).

I've attempted multiple solutions, but none of them was compatible with a Windows Store App.

No brush:

> - RadialGradientBrush is not supported in a Windows App project.
> - DrawingBrush is not supported in a Windows App project.
> - The type 'VisualBrush' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

No mask:

> - The attachable property 'OpacityMask' was not found in type 'Image'.
> - The attachable property 'OpacityMask' was not found in type 'StackPanel'.
> - The attachable property 'OpacityMask' was not found in type 'Grid'.

No rounded geometry:

> - The property 'RadiusX' was not found in type 'RectangleGeometry'.
> - MultiBinding is not supported in a Windows App project.

Is it something technically impossible in a C#/XAML Windows store app?

Comment: `OpacityMask` isn't supported yet in WinRT, and for `Clip` you're going to be restricted to `RectangleGeometry` so I guess it really depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried MS solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750631.aspx for a RectangleGeometry with rounded corners, and it fails as well. Did they purposely removed all thinkable ways to clip with a rounded shape?

Comment: Did you try to render it via a `Path` element or a `UIElement` ? You won't be able to apply it to `Path` but I believe you could apply it directly to a `UIElement` like maybe;  `<Grid Clip="ClipData"/>`

Comment: It is polite to mark the best/correct answer.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Except that I can't agree with the impossibility of programming a simple UI aspect in a software: round corners. It is like the third time I'm facing impossible issues with XAML: previous ones were "control over an animated WebView" and "binding inside an ApplicationBar". I never faced this many restrictions before. As I don't want to start hating developing for Windows 8, I want to find workarounds. I pray for a better answer than yours.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried putting your control inside a border? Just set the border's corner radius to 150 and you have a perfectly round control. Here's an example with a button.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="center" Width="200" CornerRadius="150">

        <Button x:Name="btnPlayback" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="center" Width=" 200" BorderThickness="0"  Click="btnPlayback_Click_1"/>

    </Border>
```

Comment: Excellent approach. Button shape cannot be manipulated directly but adding them as a child to a border essentially gives the same result. Programmatically, buttons can be added to a border object using the `Border.Child` property. Also, circular buttons can be made by setting the `CornerRadius` to 150.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="http://cfile3.uf.tistory.com/image/26616E4D514A3CDC136C4B"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Can you use ImageBrush?

I works well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have answered your own question. :) Just don't like the answer?

In WPF your options to clip are almost limitless. Even SilverLight had some great options. But, in Windows 8 (right now) you are limited to `RectangleGeometry`. End of story. It is worth pointing out that you can apply a `Transform` to a `RectangleGeometry` which gives you a little more insofar as options.

(at least now you know)

Best of luck!