# How to clipping by PathGeometry in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to clip a Grid by a dynamic PathGeometry and it's PathFigure.

In WPF application UIElement.Clip has some properties like CombinedGeometry,PathGeometry ... But in UWP there's only RectangleGeometry.

I'm very new to .Net and stuck on this right now, does anyone know the equivalent way in UWP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip

According to MSDN,

> **Remarks**
>
> *The clipping geometry for **UIElement.Clip** in the Windows Runtime API
>   **must** be a RectangleGeometry. You **can't** specify a non-rectangular
>   geometry, as is permitted in some XAML frameworks like Microsoft
>   Silverlight.* The clipped area is the "outside" of the geometry. In
>   other words, the content that is shown (not clipped) is the area of
>   the rectangle that is drawn with Fill if the geometry were used as
>   data for a Path rather than for clipping. The clipped area is any area
>   that falls outside the rectangle. The clipped area isn't hit-testable.

As [@Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265706/jerry-nixon-msft) pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446850/1061092),

> you can apply a `Transform` to a `RectangleGeometry` which gives you a
>   little more insofar as options.