# How to make Round Corners for CaptureElement in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, border

I need to have a round corners for CaptureElement in UWP. I tried adding border for this element with corner radius. it seems a border is creating but the CaptureElement is not getting cropped at the corners. Below is the code I am working on.

```
     <StackPanel RelativePanel.Below="Seperator2" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True">
                <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#E4F7FF" CornerRadius="10">
                <controls:DropShadowPanel Name="PreviewShadow" BlurRadius="8.0" ShadowOpacity="0.1" OffsetX="-10" OffsetY="10" Color="Black">
                    <CaptureElement Name="previewcontrol" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="260" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="345" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                </Border> </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Clip the CaptureElement

Comment: Clip doesnt work in uwp. clip only has rectangle geometry with rect(); it doesnt support radius x or radius y.

Comment: can you use win2d?

Comment: win2d works only in wpf i think.

Comment: WPF cant use win2d that only work in uwp.

Comment: Can you use that line https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800312/6116637

Comment: I already checked that question. didnt help

Comment: year, the win2d can do well and you can search `win2d` in store and download to use it

Comment: A bit more light on my case is appreciated. help me do it with win2d if possible

Comment: I dont know how to do it but I think it can do.

Answer (score 0):

A quick work-around is to just fake it by giving the *illusion* that the element is being clipped by utilizing the natural zindex of the DOM and essentially floating your `Border` over the top of the element.

Example image;
[image]

Quick PoC XAML;

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">

   <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
      <CaptureElement/>
       <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="10" 
               CornerRadius="20" Margin="-10"/>
   </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great workaround. I can't use this trick as I am having  a drop shadow for the capture element. So a border like this will ruin that. Any other trick?

Comment: @Anonymous what if you add `Background="Transparent"` to the `Border` and apply your drop shadow to the border instead? Is that more of the result you're looking for?

Comment: Tried. Setting background="transparent" wont help. But setting the border to the background colour will fix the issue. But still not a proper fix. I have a Custom background image. So I can't give a fixed colour to it properly. Anyway Thanks for your suggestion. I hope there are more ways ..